# “Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response”

Tags: angular5

**service.ts :**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
    // headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'X-Requested-With' }),
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':'true','Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'X-PINGOTHER,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization','Access-Control-Expose-Headers':'xsrf-token' }),
    params: new HttpParams({})
};


@Injectable()
export class DemoService {

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

    postData(doctor) {
        let new_doctor = JSON.stringify(doctor);
        return this.http.post('http://a.com/api/doctors/doctor', new_doctor, httpOptions);
    }

    get_doctor_list() {
        return this.http.get('http://a.com/api/doctors/doctor');
    }

    update_doctor_details(data,id) {
        let details = JSON.stringify(data);
        return this.http.put('http://a.com/api/doctors/doctor/id/' + id, details, httpOptions);
    }
}


component

    onSubmit(createdoctor:NgForm) {
        this.doctor_details = createdoctor.value;
        this.notvalid = createdoctor.valid == true?false:true;
        let date = new Date();
        let created_date = this.datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        this.doctor_details.Id = this.maxid;
        this.doctor_details.create_date = created_date;
        this.doctor_details.status = "1";
        this._demoService.postData(this.doctor_details).subscribe(
            error => {
                console.error("Error saving data!");
            }
        );
    }
```

But I got the `error` :

> Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I am a beginner in angular 5. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

CORS headers, those that start with `Access-Control-` are **response headers**, they must be set by and sent from the server to the browser, not the other way around, that's the reason for your error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The violating reason was having a `HttpInterceptor` in the Angular app config:

```js
    const secureReq = req.clone({ body: newBody });
    return next.handle(secureReq);
```

Even this code did not really do anything, it caused the extraneous headers to appear in HTTP GET requests going to external services and triggered HTTP OPTIONS request. Just make sure that your inceptor does not mess with external resources:

```js
    if(!req.url.startsWith("https://myapiservice.io")) {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
```