# OPTIONS Error using twitter API (400)

Tags: angularjs, api, twitter, cors

For my personal website, I'd like to create a page summarizing my social presence.

I used [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) to make sure all my queries are valid.
So I made simple call to get my last post on twitter.

Everything works find on [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop), so there isn't any Authorization issues.

But when it comes to implement it on my client (using [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/) ), I'm getting this error:

> **OPTIONS** https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id=1106474965 400 ()
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id=1106474965. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400

I know it may be related to  [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work) but I can't configure the server as I subscribed a shared hosting
([One.com](https://www.one.com/fr/)).

I tried to  [reset my $httpProvider default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource/20516179#20516179)  in vein.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Twitter API doesn't support CORS headers, and that's why your preflight tests are failing:
https://twittercommunity.com/t/will-twitter-api-support-cors-headers-soon/28276