# Angular $http options instead post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, http, post

I make `$http POST` request to a server api but request method changes to `OPTIONS`.
I do it all with localhost. So I did the same request through the Postman and everything works

Service:

```
function httpReg(userData) {
            console.log(userData)
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: CONFIG.APIHost + '/auth/signup',
                data: {
                    "username": userData.username,
                    "email":userData.email,
                    "password": userData.password
                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                }
            });
        }
```

Screenshot:
[image]
<sub>(source: [joxi.net](http://joxi.net/Q2KLwPyUPE5jAj.png))</sub>

Comment: This is probably a CORS problem with your server (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12112294/5122581). Since Postman has higher privileges than web content, it does not run into the same problem.

Comment: If `CONFIG.APIHost` is a different server, it's likely trying to initiate [CORS](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Flowchart_showing_Simple_and_Preflight_XHR.svg)

Comment: Neither `$http` nor angular nor javascript have anything to do with it. The browser does that for cross origin requests. The endpoint needs to be CORS enabled

Comment: CONFIG.APIHost  is a different server

Comment: CORS requests that aren't simple require an OPTIONS preflight. If your server doesn't support said preflight, the request will be rejected by the browser. Fix the server.

Comment: That is a normal pre-flight OPTIONS request and the server is returning good CORS headers. So what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Actually your `preflight` request is bounced back.

If the browser doesn't trusts the data source you are hitting the browser first sends a `preflight` request to that server and if that returns `200OK`, then browser will send your original request.

The applies only to browsers, and other tools such as `postman` dosen't send and preflight requests, so your code might work their.

How to solve the problem.

- Add headers for accepted options `GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT` to the requested resource.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it looks like cors problem.

Try one of the following:

1. Try to set the referrer in your header
2. Try this:

   ```
   app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
      //Reset headers to avoid OPTIONS request (aka preflight)
     $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
     $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
     $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
     $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
   }]);
   ```
3. Remove the `x-auth*` settings from *_app.js* file of your *yeoman/gulp* settings.

Reference: [AngularJS performs an OPTIONS HTTP request for a cross-origin resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource)