# Http.Delete doesn't work

Tags: angular

Http.Delete doesn't working on angular 5.2.0

The Code is:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
this.http.delete(this.url + encodeURIComponent(key.id), {headers : headers})
                           .toPromise();
```

The error message is:
Failed to load http://localhost/project/bfd19ece-f4a1-4935-ae3f-d5ea28969871: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403

[image]

Edit: 
The delete is working using fiddler composer

Edit:
The problem is solved by open chrome by run this

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

From this link: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 403 is "Forbidden" - doesn't sound like it's anything to do with angular, your webserver didn't like that request at all

Comment: Thanks, but it works in fiddler http request so there is no problem with backend

Comment: Your fiddler output shows that you are doing a `GET`, not a `DELETE`

Comment: Sorry I updated the wrong image

Comment: Now it's `OPTIONS` and not `DELETE`

Comment: This is not fiddler request .. it's angular request for the above code

Comment: My bad... either way, I've posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with angular, it's that the OPTIONS request made by angular (to find out whether it can do a cross domain request) is failing with a 403.

Your origin is different to the requested URL so it needs to check that it's allowed to make the request.

[This SO post may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource)

Comment: Thanks, I will check and get back to you

Comment: hi Scott, I have down voted you mistakenly, do mock edit to be able to remove the downvote