# How do I setup React in one server and springboot in another server?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, maven, npm

How do I setup the following :

Web Server : react + typescript application using npm - http://server1:19000/enter

Backend Server : Springboot http://server2:20000/api

I am using webpack to build the react application and springboot using mvn

Os : Windows

Answer (score 0):

in `application.properties` on springBoot you can set

```
server.port = 8090
```

With react you can set the port

```
webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80
```

it's the most easier way to set port, if you google a little you will find another ways.

i hope it usefull

Comment: thanks for the info. I want to connect these two. when I submit a form from react, it has to go springboot and respond back. The url of springboot need to be  configured, but dont know where.

Comment: cross orign error ? if you are run local, your url is `localhost:port`,

Comment: strong reference for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984329/invalid-cors-request-for-put-with-angularjs/54984424#54984424