# AngularJS passing data to $http.get request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-framework

I have a function which does a http POST request. The code is specified below. This works fine.

```
 $http({
   url: user.update_path, 
   method: "POST",
   data: {user_id: user.id, draft: true}
 });
```

I have another function for http GET and I want to send data to that request. But I don't have that option in get.

```
 $http({
   url: user.details_path, 
   method: "GET",
   data: {user_id: user.id}
 });
```

The syntax for `http.get` is

**get(url, config)**

Answer (score 959, accepted):

An HTTP GET request can't contain data to be posted to the server. However, you can add a query string to the request.

angular.http provides an option for it called `params`.

```
$http({
    url: user.details_path, 
    method: "GET",
    params: {user_id: user.id}
 });
```

See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#get and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage (shows the `params` param)

Comment: this will return a promise

Comment: The code with the promise:  $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // this callback will be called asynchronously
      // when the response is available
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error status.
    });

Comment: Angular also provides the functionality in the `$http.get(url.details_path, {params: {user_id: user.id}})`.

Comment: This aproach doesn't allow to send complex objects

Comment: It would have been nice to keep the object key consistent between HTTP verbs... having data for POST and params for GET is counterintuitive.

Comment: I dont understand the Angular documentation here. it says `$http.get()` may include a "config object", but no link is given whatsoever, explaining what in the world a config object is meant to include.......

Comment: @HubertPerron Actually it is not counterintuitive since these are different things: DATA can represent an object/model, even nested, and becomes part of the POST header... PARAMS represent what you can add to the GET url, where each property represents a part of the querystring in the url. It's good that they have different naming because it makes you aware of the fact that you are doing something different.

Comment: @HubertPerron don't forget, also, that a POST request can have both data AND query parameters as well.

Comment: Works Angular 1.3.2

Answer (score 529):

You *can* pass params directly to `$http.get()` The following works fine

```
$http.get(user.details_path, {
    params: { user_id: user.id }
});
```

Comment: This works but the params object is being converted into String. How do i retain the original object?

Comment: @wdphd It is inherent to HTTP that it wll be encoded to a query string

Comment: @Uli Köhler: Yup, Missed this. I was thinking along the lines of UI router where you can specify the params data type. Fixed this with a simple parseInt on the backend.

Comment: This is the correct solution if you want to add GET parameters to the given URL and works perfectly fine.

Comment: Some co workers have a concern with the lenght of thr url, is this really an issue?

Comment: @Juan, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 45):

Starting from **AngularJS v1.4.8**, you can use
[**`get(url, config)`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get)  as follows:

```
var data = {
 user_id:user.id
};

var config = {
 params: data,
 headers : {'Accept' : 'application/json'}
};

$http.get(user.details_path, config).then(function(response) {
   // process response here..
 }, function(response) {
});
```

Comment: But this data still isn't in a request body.

Comment: @naXa GET should be url params only by convention, so many frameworks will not allow it to enforce best practice, even if technically it could work and could make sense.

Comment: If only the AngularJS documentation could have provided this simple example!

Comment: @Arpit Aggarwal would you be so kind in having a look at my similar question with golang web server and vue.js? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61520048/how-to-exchange-data-between-go-web-server-and-vue-js-frontend-http-post-404?noredirect=1#comment108824929_61520048

Answer (score 34):

Solution for those who are interested in sending params and headers in GET request

```
$http.get('https://www.your-website.com/api/users.json', {
        params:  {page: 1, limit: 100, sort: 'name', direction: 'desc'},
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='}
    }
)
.then(function(response) {
    // Request completed successfully
}, function(x) {
    // Request error
});
```

Complete service example will look like this

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

mainApp.service('UserService', function($http, $q){

   this.getUsers = function(page = 1, limit = 100, sort = 'id', direction = 'desc') {

        var dfrd = $q.defer();
        $http.get('https://www.your-website.com/api/users.json', 
            {
                params:{page: page, limit: limit, sort: sort, direction: direction},
                headers: {Authorization: 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='}
            }
        )
        .then(function(response) {
            if ( response.data.success == true ) { 

            } else {

            }
        }, function(x) {

            dfrd.reject(true);
        });
        return dfrd.promise;
   }

});
```

Comment: How would the response data be used in a controller? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can even simply add the parameters to the end of the url:

```
$http.get('path/to/script.php?param=hello').success(function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Paired with script.php:

```
<? var_dump($_GET); ?>
```

Resulting in the following javascript alert:

```
array(1) {  
    ["param"]=>  
    string(4) "hello"
}
```

Comment: does $http do any escaping?

Comment: This works too but the issue with this is that when you have multiple parameters it becomes a pain adding them to the end of the url plus if you change a variable name you have to come and change it in the url as well.

Comment: I know. It was more a demonstration, showing that *you can even do it the regular way*, I don't necessarily recommend it. (Where 'regular way' means how you've probably done it for years with php)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete example of an HTTP GET request with parameters using angular.js in ASP.NET MVC:

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public class AngularController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult GetFullName(string name, string surname)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        return Json(new { fullName = String.Format("{0} {1}",name,surname) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp = angular.module("app", []);

    myApp.controller('controller', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.GetFullName = function (employee) {

            //The url is as follows - ControllerName/ActionName?name=nameValue&surname=surnameValue

            $http.get("/Angular/GetFullName?name=" + $scope.name + "&surname=" + $scope.surname).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert('Your full name is - ' + data.fullName);
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("An error occurred during the AJAX request");
            });

        }
    });

</script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">

    <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="surname" />
    <input type="button" ng-click="GetFullName()" value="Get Full Name" />
</div>
```

Comment: IMHO The syntax with `params` is less error prone than a 'manual' url concat

Answer (score 1):

For sending get request with parameter i use

```
  $http.get('urlPartOne\\'+parameter+'\\urlPartTwo')
```

By this you can use your own url string