# AngularJS - Send $http GET request with associative array params

Tags: angularjs, http, angularjs-http

with this code I am trying to send a $http.get request to my rest service:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/item/all',
    params: {
        query: {
            userid: 7
        },
        fields: 'title'
    }
});
```

I expected to access this URL:

```
/api/item/all?query[userid]=7&fields=title
```

but I am always getting a malformed url...

So, how to proceed?

Or even better: Is it possible to pass the full request url into the url-param of $http?

Comment: You should be fine to write the url with the full query string unless there are variables

Comment: could try `"query[userid]" : 7 , fields: 'title'`

Comment: @ExplosionPills the user id is a variable... should I first create a string with the url and then pass it to $http?

Comment: @charlietfl already tried... doesn't pass the variable at all.

Comment: OK. I didn't realize it was a variable. Can you change back end, that's an ugly looking url especially since `userid` is a variable. Alternatively creating the string in advance is not an issue either

Comment: Exact duplicate of [AngularJS passing data to $http.get request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760070/angularjs-passing-data-to-http-get-request). The solution is to use the `params` option.

Comment: If you are facing AngularJS specific serialization problem, then httpParamSerializerJQLike is what you need. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33852190/angularjs-get-ajax-call-with-array-parameters

Answer (score -4, accepted):

In a GET request, you should pass parameters as part of the query string.

You can use the shortcut get call and pass in the query parameters in the url:

```
$http.get('api/item/all?userid=" + 7 + "&fields=title");
```

If you need to access them as scope variables, you can do that too:

```
$http.get('api/item/all?userid=" + $scope.foo + "&fields=" + $scope.bar);
```

Also depending on the back end you can send them as a path parameters rather then a query parameter:

```
$http.get('api/item/all/userid/" + $scope.foo + "/fields/" + $scope.bar);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Please don't build query strings by hand! You'll have to escape the values manually. Much better to use the [`params` option of the config object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760070/angularjs-passing-data-to-http-get-request).

Comment: I have to emphatically agree with Dan Dalcalescu. I'm currently dealing with a lot of issues on our web app because someone prior built up strings by hand. Why choose a fragile methodology as best practice rather than using the framework that you've been provided?