# What is the Angular Equivalent for Jquery Ajax?

Tags: ajax, angularjs

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../Home/RightPanel",
            data:{"movie_name":$(".search_columns").val()},
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (res) {
               $("#right_panel").html(res);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

I tried using $http instead of $.ajax. But it didn't work.

Comment: inject $http in your controller or service. then try $http.get()

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole section in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) on how to use it:

> The `$http` service is a core Angular service that facilitates communication with the remote HTTP servers via the browser's **XMLHttpRequest** object or via **JSONP**.
>
> The `$http` service is a function which takes a single argument — a configuration object — that is used to generate an HTTP request and returns a promise with two `$http` specific methods: *success* and *error*.

Simple GET request example :

```
$http.get('/someUrl').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
```

Simple POST request example (passing data) :

```
$http.post('/someUrl', {msg:'hello word!'}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to send data in an $http GET request. You can either send you data as query string parameter or you can make a POST request. JQuery automatically converts the values in data in query string parameters.

GET request with query string parameter:

```
$http.get("../Home/RightPanel", 
{
params: { movie_name: $(".search_columns").val() }
});
```

You can find more examples at [AngularJS passing data to $http.get request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760070/angularjs-passing-data-to-http-get-request).