# ASP.NET Web API 2 with Angular woes

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

This is a development of a [question that I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29559507/web-api-2-rest-get-not-receiving-parameters-angular/29560530#29560530) earlier that changed into a different problem.

My Web API 2 controller is successfully being hit, but the view model passed as a parameter is not being populated. It contains nulls for strings and falses for booleans.

My controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<string> Post(SearchParameters id)
{
    return null;
}

public struct SearchParameters
{
    string brokerIsUnallocated;
    string brokerIncludeDeleted;
    string businessType;
    bool codeC;
    bool codeD;
    bool codeP;
    bool codeS;
    bool codeT;
    bool codeX;
    string companyName;
    string contactName;
    string country;
    string customerId;
    string department;
    string selectedBroker;
    string town;
}
```

I have checked in Fiddler and every parameter is being passed. Do I somehow need to pass this as a parameter called ID to match the controller action? I am using the default routing, like this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Fiddler request looks like this:

[image: Fiddler capture]

Looking forward to your responses.

Comment: I would guess, from your last question, that your data isn't in the correct JSON format

Comment: It looks like the same issue with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618471/web-api-put-is-recognizing-query-strings-but-not-body/21618545#21618545 . Check out my answer in the question

Answer (score 0):

Change your definition to:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Post([FromBody]SearchParameters id)
{
    return null;
}
```

The notation `FromBody` should serialize your data.

Comment: Your return type also should be : IHttpActionResult, not IEnumerable<string>.

Comment: I have implemented your responses serially and together but now my controller action is not being hit at all. I am getting a 404.

Comment: What your route definition data look like? Paste it in your question, please.

Comment: Route definitions added above. I think the route is working because the controller action was being hit when I had my original method signature.

Comment: Well, nothing bad, i presume. Can we see that "Fiddler" you mention in the question?

Comment: I have added Fiddler's request. It's not a particularly useful capture because I didn't add any parameters to the search, but I assure you that even with a completely populated view model the action has null values in the parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74933/discussion-between-serlingpa-and-netrevisanto).