# Set a value in angular with jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs

I want to create a dynamic page (that's why i'm using [angular.js](https://angularjs.org/)) according to datas from my localhost database. I'm connecting into my DB using a jQuery ajax call function :

```
var ajaxCall = function(request,datas,async,onSuccess){
    $.ajax({
        async: async,
        url: 'data.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            request: request,
            datas: datas
        },
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(returns){
            if(onSuccess != null)
                onSuccess(returns);
        }
    });
};
```

This is my angular file, including the ajaxCall to get my values :

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('user', [ ]);

    app.controller('MemberController', function() {
         var user= this;
         user.members= [];

         ajaxCall("getMember",null,false,function(result){
             for(var number in result)
                 user.members.push(result[number]);
         });

         setTimeout(function(){
             console.log(user.members)
         }, 2500);
     });
})();
```

From the ajax call, I receive a JSON (valid on [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)) but in my angular code, when I `console.log(user.members)` (even with a TimeOut of several seconds), the value of the array is still `[]` and I can't use it on my html page.

Do you have any idea why ? Or how can I change my code to make it work ? Thank you !

Comment: can you post the angular controller too

Comment: Please put your `console.log` right before the closing `});` of your example code. This would be the only correct place to check user.members

Comment: People, stop mixing jQuery and Angular. Stop using jQuery's ajax instead of Angular's $http service. _Unload_  jQuery and find a 100% Angular way of doing things.

Comment: After following most of angular tutorial on codeschool, I wanted to .. But I didn't know how to call my localhost database with a $http injection.
I also had an already-made function on jQuery, that's why I wanted to try with both together. Have you got a link (tutorial, video, SO topic ...) to show me how I can access localhost databases ?

@sanjeev Edited :)

Comment: `$http` syntax is the same as `ajax`. `$http.get("someUrl", { "some":"data"}).success(function(data){ /* do something with data */}).error(function(err){ console.log(err) })` . The only difference is, it works directly in Angular without any dirty workaround.

Comment: You should not do 'for in'. Instead do 'for of' if es6 is supported, or a regular 'for (var i...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[enter link description here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)Inside your AJAX callback you need to tell Angular that you have changed it's model, outside Angular world.

```
ajaxCall("getMember",null,false,function(result){
             for(var number in result)
                 user.members.push(result[number]);
             $scope.$apply(); // this will tel Angular to loop for changes in $scope
         });
```

But I would encourage you to replace it with $http call:

```
app.controller('MemberController', function($http) {

         $scope.members = [];

         $http.post("data.php" ,{ request: request, datas: datas })
        .success(function(result){
             console.debug(result);
             for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++)
                 $scope.members.push( result[i] );
         });
     });
```

With this code you don't need to call `$apply`, because $http is Angular service, and `$apply` will be called automaticaly at the end of success predicate.

More about `$http.get` with arguments you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760070/angularjs-passing-data-to-http-get-request). `$http` with post is inside this answer.

Update:

You should assign members to controller `$scope`, that way your results will be visible on the view (I've updated my code).

Secondly you said, that your action on server side is a read operation, in this case replace your `POST` with `GET`, like so:

```
 $http.get("data.php" ,{params: { request: request, datas: datas } })
```

Remember:

1. `POST` - when you remove, add, update model
2. `GET` - when you read objects

Good luck:)

Comment: Secondly, when working with AJAX, don't trust timeout to check it's results, you need to change your logic, and use fetched data inside succes predicate, rather than wait x seconds.

Comment: That helped me a lot .. But one more thing : I edited my post to show you my ajaxCall function, and I don't know how make the $http injection look like it (wih $_REQUEST values and things like that), do you have any idea ?

Comment: @tektiv I've updated the answer, see if it helps. As you can see, Angular is shorter, and code is still readable:)

Comment: I like your new way, I could do a new function with it .. But it doesn't work : it lets me know that there are 2 items on database, but doesn't send anything. Any idea why ? ("Response" in FireBug shows up, but shows nothing)

Comment: What response code do you receive? Can you debug into it on server side? In my example you are calling POST method, so I assume this will persist something. For fetching data, use get.

Comment: I don't send any data when I do the $http call, I don't need it, my $sql is a SELECT.          I'm sending a request var because I have a switch in my data.php with every case of request (including "getMember" which echo the result of a JSON created in PHP with what I have from the SELECT query).       But fnally, I don't receive anything : my user.members is still [] after the $http call

Comment: Perfect, that works very well ! Thank you again, and sorry about bothering you !

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('yourController', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.user = {
      data: []
    };
    $http.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/one/1/two/2/three/3').success(function(results) {
      console.log(results);
      for (var number in results)
        $scope.user.data.push(results[number]);
    });
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<html ng-app="app">

<body ng-controller="yourController">

  {{user.data}}

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not my favorite way to do it but in your case call:

```
$scope.$apply();
```

After you've updated your collection.

I think what's happening is that Angular needs to run a digest cycle to update views and right now you haven't told it to do that because you're running a straight ajax call.  If your call was initiated by an "ng-"event angular would then know that stuff is going on and wait for calls to finish...before updating the views for itself.

So try the $scope.$apply(); at first and if you can call your update function via an ng-click or something try that without the $scope.$apply(); and see if that works as well.

Then you should look into using $http to make REST calls I personally like the ng-resource add-on module...

Comment: See my comment above. That's what happens when you mix jQuery and Angular. jQuery is outside Angular's "world", it's clumsy, and you need dirty tricks like `$scope.$apply()` to tinker and make things work. Definitely not the way to go. The answer is correct, note.

Comment: Maybe true, but this is all part of the learning process, and I didn't want to offer up a solution of: It's all crap, re-write everything...so try to find a solution for the jQuery ajax call, that way we can all learn how things work, and then make a judgement about what technology to use in another instance.

Comment: I agree, I said your solution works. But since the OP is learning (as we all do), my best advice is : STOP that, remove jQuery and find an Angular way of doing things. Tring to mix both won't do any good and that's not a good way to learn.