# Query a SQL server database with AngularJS and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I am experienced in ASP.NET and web/database applications; I am learning and trying out Angular.
I found a very good database example at w3schools.com, here:

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_sql.asp

(see sections "Fetching Data From an ASP.NET Server Running SQL" and "4. Server Code ASP.NET, VB Razor and SQL Lite").

The Angular code is just:

```
$http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_sql.aspx")
```

and the sample query in the aspx page is:

```
"SELECT CompanyName, City, Country FROM Customers"
```

My problem is, there is no explanation of how to pass parameters to a query similar to this:

```
"SELECT CompanyName, City, Country FROM Customers Where Country = " & txtSomething
```

I know how to change the aspx page to read parameters on the ASP.NET side, but I don't know how to pass them from the Angular code.

How should I modify this Angular code to pass parameters to the aspx page?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_sql.aspx")
    .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Probably a dup of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760070/angularjs-passing-data-to-http-get-request

Comment: Thank you, I missed it, will take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a query string to the request.

angular.http provides an option for it params.

$http({
    url: "http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_sql.aspx", 
    method: "GET",
    params: {id: someId}
 });

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest option is probably to add query string parameters:

```
"htp://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_sql.aspx?country=" + $scope.country
```