# AngularJS-ionic framework http.get error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, http-get

I'm trying to use http.get with ionic framework. I've made a API REST with Slim framework.

When i try this in my services.js:

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost/API_Rest/api.php/user/jean/pass/jeanvaljean' }).success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
});
```

I've this error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET http://localhost/API_Rest/api.php/user/jean/pass/jeanvaljean
No more request expected
    at $httpBackend (angular-mocks.js:1211)
    at sendReq (ionic.bundle.js:18327)
    at $get.serverRequest (ionic.bundle.js:18043)
    at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:21888)
    at ionic.bundle.js:21904
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:23100)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:22916)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:23205)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:53457)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:11713)
```

If you need more informations ask me.

Thank's!

EDIT:
I've add this line before the GET: `$httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough();`

And now i've this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost/API_Rest/api.php/user?name=g&pass=ezg. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

EDIT 2: I've found the problem it was on my API, i've to specify the header : header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

Comment: Install a chrome extension: Rest client ,call the api from there to check if it returns data.

Comment: Hi, i use Postman and the api return me this: http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/749420PostmanGoogleChrome.jpg

Comment: Is this what it should return? What was the payload sent ? I dont see any request params in the Get here.

Comment: Yeah this is the good return, i've write directly the params in the url. In this url (http://localhost/API_Rest/api.php/user/jean/pass/jeanvaljean) jean is param and jeanvaljean is a another param

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760070/angularjs-passing-data-to-http-get-request

Comment: You ll probably have to change the url to a relative path and send the request params as in the answer above.

Comment: My new path is (http://localhost/API_Rest/api.php/user) and i use your answer for write my GET in my js but i've the same error... my get ($http({
                url: '/API_Rest/api.php/user',
                method: 'GET',
                params: { name: name, pass: pw }
            });)