# passing data using AngularJS $http.get method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, express, mean-stack

I'm building an application using the MEAN stack that would make use of data retrieved from an external API. As a measure to hide the API key, I want to make the API request from the server, however I am having problems passing the search term from the Angular front-end to the server.

The code below is part of the Angular controller, which should pass the request to the server with the search term:

```
myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope','$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location){
        $scope.submit = function(){
        $location.path('/results');
        $http({method: 'GET', url: '/makeSearch', data: {term: $scope.term} });
    }
}]);
```

and then the following server code would parse the request using the `body-parser` middleware:

```
app.get('/makeSearch', function(req, res) {
console.log("I received a command!");
console.log(req.body); });
```

However once I try to pass/submit a search term from the front-end, I get only an empty object on the server console. Any tips on what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why are you sending the request after changing your location ?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out! @Rikky made a good point that the body of a http get request (`req.body`) is always empty. So by logging just the `req` to the console, I worked out how the search term can be sent using the GET method

Using `params` instead of `data` in the request within the AngularJS controller show in the code below:

```
revApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope','$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location){

$scope.submit = function(){
    console.log($scope.term);
    $location.path('/results');
    $http({method: 'GET',
        url: '/makeSearch',
        params: {term: $scope.term}
    });
} }]);
```

and on the server, logging `req.query` instead of `req.body` as shown in the code below:

```
app.get('/makeSearch', function(req, res) {
console.log("I received a command!");
console.log(req.query); });
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2):

There are some http basic that you should know first, then you'll know what you are doing, then, you'll know how to do it right:

- With HTTP GET method means querying for data, not sending data. Because of that, an HTTP request with **GET** method will not have body, so

  request.body

will always be empty.

- If you **really** want to send some data to the server, using **POST** is preferred.
- If you still want to send data to the server via get, using query string is the best option. You can check it out at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760070/angularjs-passing-data-to-http-get-request?rq=1) question
- If you want to send some data to the server via get method, but you don't want using query string, you can do some *hack* with http header instead of http body.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a term property in your scope.

```
myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope','$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location){

        $scope.term ='';

        $scope.submit = function(){
           $location.path('/results');
            $http({method: 'GET', url: '/makeSearch', data: {term:    $scope.term} 
            });
     }
}]);
```

Make sure that your UI has an element which is bound to the term property of your scope

```
<input type="text" ng-model="term" />
```

Comment: Wouldn't that `$location.path('/results')';` cause a problem? Since its being executed right before the `GET`.

Comment: @Dayan, I've commented that out but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Shiyu, I already have my input bound to the term property, and I've also added the `$scope.term = '' ` but it still logs an empty object.