# Laravel search with multiple conditions

Tags: laravel, search, query-builder

I am performing a search in table with multiple condition which can exist individually and in group. These are my codes for the process.

**Controller Code**

```php
if(\Input::has('title','category_id','type','price_max','price_min','seller_type_id','division_id','district_id','upazila_id')) {
    $data['products'] = Custom::getProducts(\Input::get('title'), \Input::get('category_id'), \Input::get('type'),\Input::get('price_max'),\Input::get('price_min'),\Input::get('seller_type_id'),\Input::get('division_id'),\Input::get('district_id'),\Input::get('upazila_id'));
} else {
    $data['products'] = \DB::table('products')->where('is_active', '=', 1)->get();
}
return view('pages.posts.list')->with($data);
```

**Custom::getProducts**

```php
public static function getProducts($title = NULL, $category_id = NULL, $type = 0, $price_max = NULL, $price_min = NULL, $seller_type_id = 0, $division_id = NULL, $district_id = NULL, $upazila_id = NULL) {
    $products = DB::table('products')
                ->where(function($query) use ($title, $category_id, $type, $price_max, $price_min, $seller_type_id, $division_id, $district_id, $upazila_id) { 
                    if ($title)
                        $query->where('title', 'like', $title);

                    if ($category_id)
                        $query->where('category_id', $category_id);

                    if ($type != 0)
                        $query->where('type', $type);

                    if ($price_max)
                        $query->where('price', '<=', $price_max);

                    if ($price_min)
                        $query->where('price', '>=', $price_min);

                    if ($seller_type_id != 0)
                        $query->where('seller_type_id', $seller_type_id);

                    if ($division_id)
                        $query->where('division_id', $division_id);

                    if ($district_id)
                        $query->where('district_id', $district_id);

                    if ($upazila_id)
                        $query->where('upazila_id', $upazila_id);
                })
                ->where('is_active', '=', 1)->get();

    return $products;
}
```

But it is not working as expected. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: And what does it mean "as expected"? What are the input values, query you expect and query you get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving records from database using eloquent with optional query parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705032/retrieving-records-from-database-using-eloquent-with-optional-query-parameters)

Comment: its not filter the data @jedrzej.kurylo

Comment: explain please @JosephSilber

Comment: Do toSql() instead of get() and paste the query you are getting there

Comment: @Alvi_1987 - Explain what? You're doing something similar to that question. Use the code I posted there.