# How to do a $http GET with some data in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I want to make a Get request to my Backend, but I want to verify some user credentials before sending the response object.

Here is my code:

```
$scope.getEverything = function (){
    $http.get('http://localhost:1234/things').success(function(data){
        $scope.things = data;
    });
};
```

I've tried the same code with the following syntax:

```
$http.method('path).then
$http.method(config)
```

And I just could not figure out how to pass in some data. Trying to use params:data as the config object with print out:

> GET http://localhost:1234/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

On the console.

The AngularJS Docs don't say a word about sending data with GET requests. I've also tried some answers of Stack, but most of then are outdated and just won't work.

Can I send data with GET request or this is just one design error of my application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're most likely going to need to use a POST method instead of a GET method.

But to do it with a GET method:

From [AngularJS passing data to $http.get request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760070/angularjs-passing-data-to-http-get-request):

> A HTTP GET request can't contain data to be posted to the server.
> However you can add a query string to the request.
>
> angular.http provides an option for it params.

```js
$http({
     url: user.details_path, 
     method: "GET",
     params: {user_id: user.id}  
});
```

And using [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to POST instead:

```
$http.post('/someUrl', {msg:'hello word!'}).
  then(function(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Comment: why are you injecting jQuery `$.ajax` into an angular question? angular has it's own ajax api

Comment: I included both for clarity

Comment: I don't think jquery should be used directly if AngularJS is in place, as that will force to use $scope.$apply and also will break the testability of angular (making Protractor stop waiting for the request to end)

Comment: I modified it so that it is 100% Angular

Comment: Ok, I'm going with POST requests. I'm using Node with Express and I have already tried using POST requests to GET filtered data based on the req.body.

Then, I'm using res.json(obj) to get data back on client. 

Thank you. I was just hoping to use the 'correct' word of method.

Comment: Ok, glad to help. Please select this answer!

Comment: @RodrigoSouza, hit the check next to this answer

Comment: I was waiting for the cooldown. :P
Checking right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For `$http.get` requests use the `params` property of the config object

```
$http.get(url, {params:{ foo:'bar'}}).then(func....
```

See the **Arguments** table in **Usage** section of [**$http docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass some data when using the GET method you can pass a `params` option on the get method of the `$http` service. This will be urlencoded parameters.

```js
$http.get(url, {
  params: {
    query: 'hello world'
  }
}
```

or

```js
$http({
   url: url,
   method:'GET',
   params: {
     query:'Hello World'
   }
})
```

But, the http standards define the POST method to send data to the server. The GET is just to obtain data from it. In Angular the POST method looks like:

```js
$http({
  url: url,
  method:'POST',
  data: {
    query: 'Hello World'
  }
})
```

Check the [official docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.18/docs/api/ng/service/$http) for [GET](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.18/docs/api/ng/service/$http#get) and [POST](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.18/docs/api/ng/service/$http#post)

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want to use query params. :/
I'm going with POST. Thanks.

Comment: Post is the rigth way to send data to the server, the get params is data that is append it to the url of the request. exp: url?query=helloworld&otherparam=23. It purpose is to refine the request options. Not send data to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var req = {
 method: 'GET',
 url: 'http://localhost:1234/things',
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @charlietfl mentioned, according to the docs you can do this to implement download loaded/total progress:

```
 $http.get(url,  {
     eventHandlers: {
         'progress': function(evt) {
             $window.console.log(evt.loaded + '/' + evt.total);
         }
     }
  }).then(function(response) { ...
```