# Angular function get data from $http requrest

Tags: angularjs

I need to fetch data via $http request and i need to use it for Edit value for my form.

**Example code**

```
 $http.get(base_url+"user/feach_one")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.json = response.data;
     $scope.name=$scope.json.name;
    });
 $scope.basic={
        name:// I want to get $scope.json.name here  
    };
```

Comment: how about $scope.basic={
        name: $scope.name 
    };

Comment: Are you getting data from response?

Comment: Put `$scope.basic=...` inside callback

Comment: @FadiAboMsalam No. It not work.

Comment: @AlekseyL.can but I think it may look messy if I have a lot of function need to use data from the callback

Comment: @SP yes my friend

Comment: var obj = JSON.parse(json.name);
obj['name'].push({"json.name"});
 var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(obj);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a $http GET with some data in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191502/how-to-do-a-http-get-with-some-data-in-angular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Bind your $scope to view, and create your form with your json params like this sample, **read the comments**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
   //json
   //uncomment in your local
   //$http.get(base_url + "user/feach_one").then(function (response) {
   //    var json = response;
   //    $scope.form = json;
   //});

   //we didn't have api here: { name: "Test", age: 20 }
   //comment in your local
   var json = { name: "Test", age: 20 }
   $scope.form = json;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form>
      <label>name</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="form.name"/>
      <label>age</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="form.age"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I have second form need to get data from $http request. example form2. Should I use $scope.form2 = json; Is there any way to reuse the data.

Comment: if your json is different you have to repeat that step again but with new param i mean "$scope.form2 = response".

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.basic= {};
$scope.advanced= {};
 $http.get(base_url+"user/feach_one")
    .then(function (response) {
     $scope.basic.name=$scope.json.name;
     $scope.advanced=$scope.json.avanced;
    });
```

Comment: it works! thank you But if I have other function need to use that data. example advanced. I need to put $scope.advance.name-$scope.json.name?

Comment: you can design the data structure as you wish since js does not care much what you do