# How to pass data from database to controller?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass a json object from database to controller in angularjs
I am new to angularjs and Don't know about syntax.

Comment: `$http.get(url).then(function(response){ $scope.json = response.data; });`. Assuming it's coming from PHP, it will have `echo json_encode($json);`

Comment: If the database is on a server, and you are fetching the JSON by AJAX, then store it in `$scope`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a $http GET with some data in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191502/how-to-do-a-http-get-with-some-data-in-angular)

Comment: And please let me know where you want, In angularjs or angular?

Comment: What Ramesh meant is: you are either using AngularJs (v1.x) or Angular (v2+) but it can't be both, and it's not clear from your post.

Comment: Thanks for your Suggestions I have done it :-)