# AngularJS $http.get not working with external domain json data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to pull data from external domain using angularjs. I dont see any issue in the console. I tried to my best and [fiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/kn4yaoco/1/). Any help or pointer would be great.

Vie Code

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">{{response}}
    <button ng-click="getData()">GET Request</button>
</div>
```

Controller code

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getData = function () {
        $http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=98007,us").success(function (response) {
            $scope.myData = response;
            console.log(response)
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: you have to pass parameters seperatly. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760070/angularjs-passing-data-to-http-get-request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine but you are missing a few things in your markup. You are missing `ng-app` and you should be doing `{{myData}}` and not `{{response}}` (because `myData` is bound to your scope and assigned to `response`, there is not variable named `response` bound to your scope). See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q2iQBzWMriS6roIRfoMQ?p=preview)

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">{{myData}}
        <button ng-click="getData()">GET Request</button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Actually the syntax [might](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice) be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using the browser dev tools what does the the network tab show ? Was the request successful, was the request even made ?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `ng-app` in body or html

By looking at your jsFiddle is clear that your issues is that you are not adding the app name in your html.

Here is your update jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kn4yaoco/3/

you can see in console that your request is giving response properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should `.then` with $http, so something like:

```
$http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=98007,us")
  .then(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
  }):
```

Best