# Angular js $http post not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, http-post

I am using http post to get the data from a webservice using the following code..

```
$http({
                method: "post",
                url: "SurveyQuestions.asmx/GetSurveyQuestions",
                data: JSON.stringify({"empl_id" : '12345' , "Year" : '2015' }),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            }).success(function (response) { //do something})
```

The above code is working fine using "get" without parameters.

and my webservice for the post is

```
<WebMethod()> _
        <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=False)> _
        Public Sub GetSurveyQuestions(ByVal Empl_id as string, ByVal Year as string)
        Try
        //get list of records
          Dim js As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer

          Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listSurveyQuestions))
        Catch ex As Exception

      End Try

    End Sub
```

Web service is executing fine and returning the data to the Method, but the response is empty in the `$http` and errored out.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @CharlieH Unexpected token { in JSON at position 3483 at Object.parse (native). FYI, when i remove the parameters and change to "get" it works. same code change to "post" throws the error.

Comment: @CharlieH It is working now.  I didn't know, that i can use "get" and include parameters in the URL itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you just try to pass the object only adding at the last in url.

This my case i am just adding the employee Id. if you send only employee object only it will also correct.

```
$scope.removeEmployee = function(employee) {

var method = 'DELETE';

var url = 'http://localhost:8080/AngularJSWithRestful/rest/product/Delete/' + employee.id  ;

$http({

    method : method,
    url : url,

}).then(function successCallback(response) {

    $scope.product = response.data.product;

    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are retrieving data and there are no changes being executed on your server (according to your comment) the best thing to do would be to change it to a HttpGet method. Then in angular you should use `params` property in the passed object to the $http function. This is because `HttpGet` does not support a message body. From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> **params** – `{Object.<string|Object>}` – Map of strings or objects which will be serialized with the paramSerializer and appended as GET parameters.

Your changed code:

```
$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "SurveyQuestions.asmx/GetSurveyQuestions",
    params: {"empl_id" : '12345' , "Year" : '2015' }, // use the params property
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
}).then(function (response) { //do something})
```

Also note that success and error are being marked as obsolete by the angular team. The recommended approach is to use `then` instead. See the same documentation link.

> #### Deprecation Notice
>
> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error.

See also [AngularJS passing data to $http.get request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13760360/1260204)