# I want to add a parameter to post request in angular . Can any body explain

Tags: angularjs, rest

Following is my code

```
$http.post(url)
    .then(function(response) {
            // success
            log.debug(response.data);
            //console.log(message);
        },
        function(response) { // optional
            // failed

        });
```

the parameter is user_id. Please help in the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
var data = {
    "user_id" : 123
    }

$http.post(url,data)
              .then(function(response) {
                  // success
                  log.debug(response.data);
                  //console.log(message);
                },
                function(response) { // optional
                  // failed
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following template.

P.S don't use the '$' sign, it was just to mark where you put the parameter data.

```js
                $http({
                    url: '',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {user_id: $parameterValue}
                }).success(function (data) {
                  
                  Do Something With data

                })
```

Answer (score 0):

A HTTP GET request can't contain data to be posted to the server. However you can add a query string to the request.

angular.http provides an option for it params.

```
$http({
    url: user.details_path, 
    method: "GET",
    params: {user_id: user.id}
 });
```

See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#get and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage (shows the params param)

Credits to [@fredrik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760070/angularjs-passing-data-to-http-get-request)