# Pass and access parameters through AngularJS http GET

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, angular-http

Beginner in `AngularJS`:
I am passing parameters through `http.get` to the url (php file). On my php file I have mysql query in which I have to read those parameters in the where clause.

In brief: http://example.com/page.php?dept=some_dept&office=some_office is my page where I have my angular controller and view part. From this I want to get the url string/params and passed to angular-data.php from where I am fecthing the response. However, angular-data.php have a sql query in which I am planning to pass the dynamic values in WHERE clause i.e. the params from angular controller (dept and office) before getting response on my view page (url given above with params)

Below is my code so far:

`page.php?dept=some_dept&office=some_office`

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'angular-data.php',
                data: {
                    param1: type,
                    param2: office
                }
            }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.names = response.data.records;
            });
        });
```

page.php?dept=some_dept&office=some_office (continue...):

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>
        {{$index + 1}}
    </td>
    <td>{{ x.Name}}.</td>
    <td>{{ x.Office}}</td>
</tr>
```

angular-data.php where I want params dynamically for WHERE clause:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "local_server");
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Dept` = " . $_GET['dept'] . " AND `Office` = " . $_GET['office'] . "");
$outp = "";
while ($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {
        $outp .= ",";
    }
    $outp .= '{"Name":"' . $rs["Name"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"Office":"' . $rs["Office"] . '"}';
}
$outp = '{"records":[' . $outp . ']}';
$conn->close();
echo($outp);
```

Comment: what is not working can you tell . ? Also is this you are posting or you want to use get ?

Comment: @YashveerSingh the query is not able to access the params passed though angular app.

Comment: have u check network tab ? do you see a request . please check that first may be you get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SQL query,you are  GETting`dept` and `office`.
You can pass these params as below.

you can use `params` : Map of strings or objects which will be serialized with the paramSerializer and appended as GET parameters.

```
$http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'angular-data.php',
          params: 'dept=some_dept, office=some_office'
    })
```

OR

```
$http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'angular-data.php',
          params: {
                     dept:"some_dept",
                     office:"some_office"
                  }
    })
```

More can be find here [`$http#config`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Actually it's opposite, i am not getting parameters in SQL query. I want to pass the parameters to sql query. Not sure, if it's possible in that way.

Comment: @Moin its difficult to get what you trying to say

Comment: http://example.com/page.php?dept=some_dept&office=some_office is my page where I have my angular controller and view part. From this I want to get the url string/params and passed to angular-data.php from where I am fecthing the response. However, angular-data.php have a sql query in which I am planning to pass the dynamic values in WHERE clause i.e. the params from angular controller (dept and office) before getting response on my view page (url given above with params). Hope that make sense :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'angular-data.php',
                params: {
            param1: 1,
            param2: 2
        }
            }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.names = response.data.records;
            });
        });
```

check more  details

[AngularJS passing data to $http.get request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760070/angularjs-passing-data-to-http-get-request)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand ,if you have a param type and office in html before send the http request. for example:

then:

```
data: {
    param1: $scope.type
}
```