# Passing dynamic url value to angular js controller

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to pass url parameter $id is dynamic value to Angularjs controller

My Angularjs:

```
$http.get('/todos/show/'+$id).success(function(data) {
  $scope.customers = data;
});
```

My Route in laravel

```
Route::get('todos/show/{id?}', function($id = null)
{
  $users = DB::table('customers')->where('id', $id)->get();
  return json_encode($users);
});
```

Can someone help me with these.

Comment: Consider `$http.post` instead. Or try using [`params`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13760360/8495123) with a different syntax

Comment: @AlekseySolovey can you create your answer?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey can you show me two ways of your answer?

Comment: By default laravel returns as json in an API request, so there is no need for the json encode.

Answer (score 0):

**===Maybe I've got it wrong. See the correct answer at the end.===**

First of all, you need setup your routerProvider: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

After, you can set a route like this:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/todos/show/:id", {
        //your content here like example of w3schools
    })
});
```

Or

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/todos/show/:id?", {
        //your content here like example of w3schools
    })
});
```

If id is an optional field.

Now, you need pass $routeParams to your controller, and you can get route data:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  console.log($routeParams.id)
}]);
```

**===Correct answer===**

Use post!
Angular:

```
$http.post('/todos/show', {id: $id}).success(function(data) {
  $scope.customers = data;
});
```

Laravel:

```
Route::post('todos/show', function(Request $request)
{
  $users = DB::table('customers')->where('id', $request->input('id'/*, 'optional default value'*/))->get();
  return json_encode($users);
});
```

Comment: I didn't get it

Comment: @TheRock he described how to pull the **id** from your URL. For example `https://website.com/#!/todos/show/21` will make `$routeParams.id` equal to `21` so then you can use it elsewhere, like send it through `$http` service

Comment: You mean i must change  my angularjs controller to your script right?

Comment: Exactly, but you can adapt it. I can't imagine how your controller can be  different from this. haha

Comment: @GabrielTadraMainginski So you mean i use  $routeParams insted of $http.get

Comment: Maybe I've got it wrong. See the correct answer at the end.