# how to transform a table of values to integrate it into an http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table of values :

```
var array = [10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

and I would like to integrate it into an http.get as parameters but in the following form :

```
id=10&id=11&id=12&id=13&id=14&id=15
```

I thought of doing the following way :

```
var url = /myUrl;
var urlParam;
  array.map(function(item) {
  urlParam += '&id=' + item ;
  return urlParam;
 });
```

but in the end my URL looks like this :

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> /myUrl&id=10&id=11&id=12&id=13&id=14&id=15
> ```

instead of :

```
/myUrl?id=10&id=11&id=12&id=13&id=14&id=15
```

for the

```
$http.get('/myUrl' + urlParam);
```

is there a better solution ?

Comment: What backend accepts URL params like that? That is not the de-facto way to specify an array as a URL parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) which is present to work with query strings of the URL.

```js
var array = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
const params = new URLSearchParams();

array.forEach(function(value) {
  params.append('id', value);
});

console.log('/myUrl?' + params.toString());
```

Since the key for the URL query parameters remains the same, it's better to send it as one key multiple values. You could use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) or send the array as is depending upon how you would want to implement it, but sending as JSON would be a better design.

```js
var array = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('id', JSON.stringify(array));
console.log('/myUrl?' + params.toString());
```

Comment: A PHP backend will accept multiple entries with the key `id[]` and decode it as an array. The [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) API is a robust solution with proper [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Comment: @georgeawg Yes, but I suggested the JSON way because today every backend technology parses the JSON easily, so the front end would remain the same regardless of the backend tech we use.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the values in the array to `id=${item}` then join each item in the array with `&`. Then just append that value to `/myurl?`

```
const array = [10,11,12,13,14,15]
const url = '/myUrl?' + array.map((item) => `id=${item}`).join('&')
console.log(url)
```

However, you might have another issue.

The url params are invalid. Depending on the server, only the first or last `id` will be passed in.

You should really do `id1=value&id2=value2` so that you can access each one. Better yet,  `id[]=value&id[]=value2`. This *should* be parsed as an array on the server.

Comment: The square brackets need to be percent encoded.

Answer (score 0):

From [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-arguments) you can pass a parameter called `params` which purpose is passing query params.

Then you can just call your url and pass the `params` in the config of the request.

You can see multiple example on [this feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760070/angularjs-passing-data-to-http-get-request).

Params is a json object, so you could just pass your array and it should work direclty !

Comment: The `params` property does not work with an array and does not produce a param string with identical keys.

Comment: @georgeawg my bad didn't know this !