# Why is the data from $http GET is not being sent in the request?

Tags: c#, angularjs

I have a GET method in my C# controller

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetEmailTemplate(List<string> ids)
```

and I'm calling it in angularJs like so:

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: apiUrl + 'api/jobs/composeEmail',
        data: JSON.stringify(ids) //i also tried ids (which is an array)
});
```

but upon hitting the api the list of ids is null... when I checked the request in the developer tools, it doesn't have the data being sent.. it's like the data config in the $http request was ignored.  What am I missing?

the request is working when I try to test the api using POSTMAN by sending a **Body** and a sample **raw** data of

```
[
 "123213",
 "444444"
]
```

Comment: [try to see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760070/angularjs-passing-data-to-http-get-request)

Answer (score 2):

Only query strings can be used in GET requests.

[REST API: Path vs. Request Body Parameters](https://dzone.com/articles/rest-api-path-vs-request-body-parameters)

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: apiUrl + 'api/jobs/composeEmail',
    params: {ids: ids}
});
```