# Refreshing of observables in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS and can't find way to resolve this Issue:

there is part from my controller:

```
$scope.$on('showMoreNotifications', function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/notifications',
        data: {
            notificationCount: 30
        },
        success: function (e) {
            $scope.notifications = e.Messages;
        }
    });
});
```

and here is html which using this controller:

```
<div class="widget" id="widget-notifications" ng-controller="NotificationsCtrl">
    <span class="title" ng-click="$parent.$broadcast('showMoreNotifications')">@*showMoreNotifications()*@
        Notifikace
    </span>
    <div class="messages">
        <div ng-repeat="item in notifications" class="message-item type-{{item.Entity}}" data-id="{{item.AuditLogId}}">
            <span class="type"></span>
            <div class="description">
                <span class="date">{{item.Date}}</span> / {{item.Message}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I click on span class title on top, controller right call to server and receives JSON data. Unfortunately dont refresh html which is associated with it. When I click second time, html refresh data from first request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I resolved my issue... It needs apply on scope

like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: Escudo.UrlHelper.baseUrl + 'Widgets/Notifications/GetLastNotifications',
    data: {
        notificationCount: 30
    },
    success: function (e) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.notifications = e.Messages;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: While the $scope.$apply() will work, is there any reason why you wouldn't want to just use the built-in $http service? No $apply is necessary when going through that.

Answer (score 6):

Your **template is not updating since your are making xhr calls using jQuery**. Those calls are considered "outside of AngularJS" world so AngularJS is not aware of them and doesn't know that it should start it automatic refresh cycle.

You **would be much better using excellent [$http service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http)** from AngularJS to make xhr calls. You would write something like:

```
$http('/notifications', {params : {
            notificationCount: 30
        }}).success(function (e) {
            $scope.notifications = e.Messages;
        });
```

There was a similar question where the answer helps migrating from jQuery's $.ajax to AngularJS $http: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12131912/1418796

Next, something not directly related, but you really don't have to broadcast events to react on the `click` event. It would be enough to write:

```
<span class="title" ng-click="myClickHandler()">
@*showMoreNotifications()*@
        Notifikace
</span>
```

and then in your controller:

```
$scope.myClickHandler = function(){
  //call $http here
}
```