# Angularjs $http VS jquery $.ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, jquery

Can I set `context` in `Angularjs $http` just like we can do it in `jQuery's $.ajax`?

```
define([
    'app'
], function(app) {

    app.controller("controller1", function($scope, $route, $http) {

        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'server.php'
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.contacts = response.data;
        });
    });
});
```

Also, there are more callbacks in jQuery's `$.ajax`, like `.done`, `.promise` which I can use them to manipulate the `context` like this below, I wonder if I can do the same in `Angularjs`?

```
$.ajax({
    type:       "GET",
    dataType:   "HTML",
    url:        'server.php',
    context:    $("#container"),
    async:      true,
    beforeSend: function() {

        $(this).html('loading...');
    },
    success: function (returndata, status, jqxhr) {
        $(this).html(returndata).hide().fadeIn();
    },
    }).fail(function() { 
        alert("error"); 
    }).done(function(returndata) {
    },
    .always(function() { 
        alert("complete"); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 24):

> Both are same
>
> $http is  referred from angular.js script
>
> $.ajax is  referred from jquery  script

- and $http  does not support `async:false`
- $.ajax  supports `async:false`

You can do it by using `angular.js` in this way

```
$http.get('server.php').success(function(response) {
            $scope.contacts = response.data;
        }).error(function(error)
    {
//some code    
});
```

but  `async:      true,` is not supported in `angular.js`.

If you need stop asynchronous callback, then you must use `$.ajax` way

More details please see this discussion : [from jquery $.ajax to angular $http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131659/from-jquery-ajax-to-angular-http)

**Edit:**

How to show hide in `angular js`

```
<div ng-show="IsShow">xx</div>



  $http.get('server.php').success(function(response) {
                $scope.contacts = response.data;
                $scope.IsShow=true;
                $scope.$apply();
            }).error(function(error)
        {
           $scope.IsShow=false; 
           $scope.$apply(); 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I know what are `**` for?

Comment: @lauthiamkok `**` is nothing. it's SO bold line mark. `$scope.$apply()` means `$scope.IsShow=true` apply for the Html. But it's maybe don't need.

Comment: THanks. I do find jquery method is easier and more straight forward. don't you think?

Comment: @lauthiamkok , Yep you can do it jquery. So why you use angular.js? you can do it by using jquery or angular.js . both are best. but angular.js helps to binding fast than jquery. Happy coding :)

Comment: could you improve the english grammar in your answer a little bit, would be easier to understand

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Function.bind()` on the function you hand to `promise.then` to maintain the context you want. For example:

```
return $http({
    method: 'GET', 
    url:'server.php'
}).then(function(response) {
    $scope.contacts = response.data;
}.bind(this));
```

However, I'm noticing that your callbacks are all manipulating elements--things you don't need to do in Angular. Is there something specific you're trying to do but unable to with a callback?

Comment: thanks Jeff. I only need to do two things like I do in `$.ajax` - 1. `beforeSend: function() {

        $(this).html('loading...');
    }` and 2 - `success: function (returndata, status, jqxhr) {
        $(this).hide().fadeIn();
    }`.

Comment: So... yeah, you should instead use a request and response interceptor and show/hide that based on the number of pending HTTP requests.