# Synchronous in angular controller

Tags: angularjs

In the following code, the controller is not invoking the third `$http.get()` call and instead goes directly goes to the end.

I want to execute all `$http.get()` requests. In my code, the third `$http.get()` depends on the second `$http.get()` result. Additionally, the second `$http.get()` depends on the first `$http.get()` result.

**Code**

Does anyone have an idea why the third `$http.get()` is not being invoked?

Comment: Use your debugger to find out why.

Comment: because your are making ajax in for loop, without waiting for promise so `data.orderedDinnerCarts` doesn't have value

Comment: @ pankajparkar You are right..
So can you pls tell me how to wait for promise...

Comment: @SANDEEPPANDA Use .then() function instead doing like this.Implement thenable structure here.

Comment: @Satyam Koyani I put then() instead of success() but still not working....

Comment: @SANDEEPPANDA The way you wrote the code is not a good practice because you have two nested for  loops and having http call inside that.

Answer (score 1):

with the way you structured your code, this code below will run before the third $http.get

```
orderDetails['orderData'] = data;
orderDetails['kitNames'] = kitNames;
orderDetails['proteins'] = proteins;
orderDetails['dietaries'] = dietaries;
orderDetails['ingredients'] = ingredients;
```

you would have to put it in the third $http.get and every other code that depends on it, and that should solve your challenge

Also, your code can be refactored, so it is more readable and understandable for you to read

Comment: But the controller not comming to the third $http.get()...If I put alert(1) inside third $http.get() its not comming

Comment: That means the third $http.get returned error, can you test it out on [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) to see if it returned results

can you post it on plnkr, and send link

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion:-

Actually this is a big issue with `angular http` call, Because `http` call does not support *async :false*

See my answer in this discussion : [Angularjs $http VS jquery $.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860207/angularjs-http-vs-jquery-ajax)

Your code look like a lot of **confusions** for call new `http` method inside of inside methods.

And your code looks like not standard format also gives lot of confusion.

So if you change any code in this file after some day's, then you need to put a microscope glass in your eye, and will see one by one lines. it's will take more  times.  So avoid `http` call only for this type of situation.

### Solution:-

Avoid `http` call means, pleas do with `Ajax` call with [`async:false`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/what-does-async-false-do-in-jquery-ajax) option

The code look like

```
$.ajax({
    type:       "GET",
    dataType:   "Json",
    url:        'Your URL',
    **async:      false,**

    success: function (returndata, status, jqxhr) {
        $(this).html(returndata).hide().fadeIn();
    }).fail(function() { 
        alert("error"); 
    })
});
```

### [Explanation About Async:false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1478322/2218635)

> Setting async to false means that the statement you are calling has to complete before the next statement in your function can be called. If you set async: true then that statement will begin it's execution and the next statement will be called regardless of whether the async statement has completed yet.