# Difficult reading JSON and add ng-repeat list list is not completed $ http $$ HashKey

Tags: json, angularjs, http, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to Angle and am finding it very nice, my problem is this:

have a ng-repeat running straight when caught the data source of a variable javascript like this:

```
var alertsq = [  

{  
    "alert":"mediun",
    "nt":"28",
    "nu":"28",
    "no":"34",
    "dtini":"2012/Jul/23",
    "no":"3",
    "dtoc":"23/7/2012",
    "dtuo":"25/7/2012",
    "id":"227529436529033216",
    "msg":"Uh oh, this could be bad. Check the door lock vendor before you book you next hotel room: http://example.co/n56emZf2"
},
{  
    "alert":"mediun",
    "nt":"28",
    "nu":"28",
    "no":"34",
    "dtini":"2012/Jul/23",
    "no":"3",
    "dtoc":"23/7/2012",
    "dtuo":"25/7/2012",
    "id":"227529436529033216",
    "msg":"Uh oh, this could be bad. Check the door lock vendor before you book you next hotel room: http://example.co/n56emZf2"
}];
```

My controller that takes the variable *alertsq*  and arrow on the scope is as follows:

```
app.controller("alertsController",function(){    
console.log(alertsq);
this.alerts =alertsq;
});
```

The cool thing is that it works and my list in `*ng-repeat*` is filled beautifully, but when I use the *$http* to load a JSON content of a file does not meet the same list: O controller code is so :

```
app.controller("alertsController", function($http,$scope){    

$http({
url: "data/alerts.json",
dataType: "json",
method: "GET",
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
   } 
}).success(function(data){
$scope.alerts= data;
console.log($scope.alerts);
}).error(function(error){
console.log(data);
console.log(error);
});
});
```

The cool thing is that JSON is coming just right the browser output in the first case
that the list is filled is as follows:

```
mainController controller.js:7


 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
     0: Object
     $$hashKey:"object:4" 
     alert: "mediun"
     dtini: "2012/Jul/23"
     dtoc: "23/7/2012"    
     dtuo: "25/7/2012"
     id: "227529436529033216"
     msg: "Uh oh, this could be bad. Check the              
     door lock vendor before you book you next hotel room:       
     http://example.co/n56emZf2"
     no:"3"    
     nt: "28"
     nu: "28"__proto__: 
    Object1: 
    Object2:
```

And this is the console output when I seek for $http JSON:

```
 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
 0: Object 
 alert: "mediun"
 dtini: "2012/Jul/23"
 dtoc: "23/7/2012"    
 dtuo: "25/7/2012"
 id: "227529436529033216"
 msg: "Uh oh, this could be bad. Check the              
 door lock vendor before you book you next hotel room:       
 http://example.co/n56emZf2"
 no:"3"    
 nt: "28"
 nu: "28"__proto__: 
Object1: 
Object2:
```

The detail is that the output obtained by the JSON via $http there is no attribute $$HashKey, and so the list in the ng-repeat is not filled :(, can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Your $http-call looks like something from jQuery. This might give you some hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131659/from-jquery-ajax-to-angular-http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you updated your controller constructor function to include `$http`, you also added `$scope`.  Changing from [inferred to explicit dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14168699/1245971) could be a problem for several reasons.

For example, the following html will display the alerts using your original controller.

```
<div ng-controller="CtrlOne as vm">
  <div ng-repeat="alert in vm.alerts">
    {{alert.alert}} - {{alert.msg}}
  </div>
</div>
```

However, your updated controller (in which you inject `$scope` explicitly) won't work with the ["controller as" syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-clarification).  The controller alias must be removed to be compatible with your new controller constructor function:

```
<div ng-controller="CtrlOne">
  <div ng-repeat="alert in alerts">
    {{alert.alert}} - {{alert.msg}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a demo of both methods: http://plnkr.co/edit/TrTFV36kQ8Llz3n2NChB?p=preview

Alternatively, you can remove `$scope` from the dependency injection, and go back to using `this.alerts` in the controller.