# How to display form submission status in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms, activity-indicator

I started to look into Angular JS and find this framework great so far.

I have a question about form submission best practices though.

I have an update data form which has `ng-controller` and `ng-submit` directives, it loads data from the server using `get` on load and `posts` data on submit.

My question is when a user clicks submit button how do I indicate that something is actually happening? E.g. display activity indicator while the action is being processed and some kind of success or failure message after it was processed.

I used jQuery to do this for ajax forms before, do I still use jQuery or there are other tools for that in Angular JS I don't know about?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with AJAX promises in angular is much straight forward. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131659/from-jquery-ajax-to-angular-http). While your request is being processed, you could show a loading icon/text whatsoever:

```
$scope.loading = true;
$http.post("http://example.appspot.com/rest/app", {"foo":"bar"})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.loading = false;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.status = status;
    $scope.loading = false;
});
```

Then just hide and show whatever indicates your loading status:

```
<p ng-show="loading">LOADING</p>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, exactly what I was asking for. Legit question and helpful answer which will help a lot of people. Don't understand those who vote for closing the question:(