# $.ajax like function for React js and Angular js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, reactjs, angular

How do I post data using React and Angular?

Is there has function like `$.ajax` for React and Angular?

I mean I need just like this post function for React and Angular

```
$.ajax{
url:"test.php",
type:"POST",
cache:false,
success...
etc.
```

Comment: `$.ajax` is jQuery... for pure JS, use `XMLHttpRequest`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

Comment: Depending on what browsers you want to support, you might be able to use fetch().  Check it out at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 2):

A tool that can perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) requests
 that will work in ***both*** `React` and `Angular?` I tend to use:

> ### axios
>
> *"A Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js"* [[ github page]](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios), [[npm page]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

---

#### Usage comparisons:

*"...takes the good parts from Angular’s $http, and throws out everything else"* 
[~ *Six essential javascript libraries - JK Nelson*](http://jamesknelson.com/six-essential-javascript-libraries/)

**<del>axios</del>** XMLHttpRequest version

```
let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST", 'http://readyourlevel.jamesknelson.com/api/grade', true);
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        if (http.status == 200)
            onGradeResult(JSON.parse(http.responseText));
        else
            onGradeError(http);
    }
};
http.onerror = onGradeError;
http.send(text);
```

> **axios** version
>
> ```
> axios({
>     url: 'http://readyourlevel.jamesknelson.com/api/grade',
>     method: 'post',
>     headers: {'Content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'},
>     data: text
> }).then(onGradeResult, onGradeError)
> ```

Comparison with Angular shortcut methods:

**<del>axios</del>** Angular (only) shortcut version

```
$http.post("http://example.appspot.com/rest/app", {"foo":"bar"})
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.data = data;
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.status = status;
  });
```

> **axios** version (works *with* Angular *and* React)
>
> ```
> axios.post('http://example.appspot.com/rest/app', { foo: 'bar' })
>   .then(function (response) {
>     console.log(response);
>   })
>   .catch(function (error) {
>     console.log(error);
>   });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

For React:

You can use fetch API from Javascript to call the service.

```
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response
  } else {`enter code here`
    var error = new Error(response.statusText)
    error.response = response
    throw error
  }
}

function parseJSON(response) {
  return response.json()
}

fetch('/users')
  .then(checkStatus)
  .then(parseJSON)
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('request succeeded with JSON response', data)
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('request failed', error)
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

The AngularJS way of calling $http would look like:

```
$http({
    url: "http://example.appspot.com/rest/app",
    method: "POST",
    data: {"foo":"bar"}
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.data = data;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.status = status;
});
```

or could be written even simpler using shortcut methods:

```
$http.post("http://example.appspot.com/rest/app", {"foo":"bar"})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.data = data;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.status = status;
});
```

There are number of things to notice:

AngularJS version is more concise (especially using .post() method)

AngularJS will take care of converting JS objects into JSON string and setting headers (those are customizable)

Callback functions are named `success` and `error` respectively (also please note parameters of each callback)

The above is just a quick example and some pointers, be sure to check AngularJS documentation for more: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

***from:*** [from jquery $.ajax to angular $http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131659/from-jquery-ajax-to-angular-http)

***For REACT:***
http://andrewhfarmer.com/react-ajax-best-practices/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [reqwest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reqwest), very similar to the jQuery api.