# connect backend code(nodejs) this with my front end code(angular framework)

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

I am a beginner in web development.I am using angular framework ,need to connect with DB using Nodejs. I am able fetch data from db using NodeJs. How to connect this with my front end code

Answer (score 1):

You have a front-end and a backend, note that front-end is not a necessity just a web front-end, it might be a mobile application as well.

Your server should be able to send back data to be helpful for any kind of programming languages in front-end, either it's a mobile app, or a React or Angular application. For this scenario and to solve this problem we can use RESTful API *(Application Programming Interface)* which simply is a [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON) sending back data from the backend, and front-end applications can work with it.

For your case, you should connect to the database using Node.js backend *(I recommend you to use a Node.js framework, such as [Express](https://expressjs.com/), [Feathers](https://feathersjs.com/), [Strapi](https://strapi.io/), or etc)* and send data back in RESTful API format,

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch data from nodejs using ajax request.
Follwoing link may help you to learn this:

Ajax Request in Angular
[from jquery $.ajax to angular $http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131659/from-jquery-ajax-to-angular-http)
You can use mysql module in nodejs for fetching data from your database.

As a newbie, you can do the above steps and then follow some tutorial that teaches how to do all this.